# Error response from daemon: make cli opts(): making volume mountpoint for volume /Users/alexf/projects/tsk/conf: mkdir /Users: operation not permitted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm getting this error

```
Error response from daemon: make cli opts(): making volume mountpoint for volume /Users/alexf/Documents/projects/tsk/conf: mkdir /Users: operation not permitted
```

when I fire off `docker-compose up`.

I've already tried quite a lot. Nothing helped.

*Additional information*:

**Chip**: Apple M1

**MacOS**: Ventura 13.4.1 (c)

Answer (score 0):

in my case restarting docker helped

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35504467)

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like the Docker daemon is unable to create a volume mountpoint due to a **permission** issue. So since Docker requires read and write access to the directories it uses for volume mounts, you should try the following steps:

1- Check the **permissions** of the target directory */Users/alexf/Documents/projects/tsk/conf* and ensure that Docker has the necessary read and write permissions. You can do this by using the `ls -l` command to view the permissions.
So if the permissions are incorrect, you can use `chmod 777 /Users/alexf/Documents/projects/tsk/conf` to grant **read**, **write**, and **execute** permissions to **all users**.

2- If the target directory is located on an external drive or network-mounted filesystem, ensure that it is **properly mounted and accessible**.

3- Restart the Docker daemon to apply any changes made to the permissions.
You can do this by running `sudo systemctl restart docker` (for SystemD distros) or `sudo /etc/rc.d/rc.docker restart` (for SysV distros).